# How to allow user to add a new folder when using the CMFCEditBrowseCtrl?

Tags: mfc

I am looking to add a `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` to my dialog:

[image: MFC EditBrowse Control]

It works:

[image: Results]

But I am unable to create a **new folder** using this approach.

How do fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnableFolderBrowseButton` has a last parameter with the name `ulBrowseFolderFlags`.

You have to define `BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS|BIF_USENEWUI`. Or use `BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE`.

Also look at the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773205(v=vs.85).aspx). If you google for the flags you find further discussion and samples.

Comment: I can't see how I can set that via the IDE or anything? My control is on the dialog resource: `    CONTROL         "",IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE,"MfcEditBrowse",WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | 0x80,17,296,322,14
`

Comment: Still you can call GetDlgCtrl or subclass the contrl and call EnableBrowseForFolder! What is the problem?

Comment: I simply mapped the control to a variable and then made the adjustment. Thank you.